# Refresh page after submit form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I've created a gallery management.
I printed the image thumbnails with a While loop.
Can I select the photos to be deleted by a checkbox and then submit the form.
when I send the form, the page refreshes, she run images unlink(), delete row query, 
but I still see the printed row with 404 (Not Found) for the image.
If i Refresh another one, works!

The code:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

//while loop

</form>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {


    $delete = $_POST['select'];

foreach ($delete as $id => $val) {

    $query="SELECT foto FROM gallery WHERE id = '$val'";
    $result1= mysql_query($query);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        unlink($output_dir . $row[foto]); 
    }

    $query="DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id = '$val'";
    $result2= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 



}



}
```

sOLVED.
EDIT:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {


    $delete = $_POST['select'];

foreach ($delete as $id => $val) {

    $query="SELECT foto FROM gallery WHERE id = '$val'";
    $result1= mysql_query($query);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        unlink($output_dir . $row[foto]); 
    }

    $query="DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id = '$val'";
    $result2= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 



}



}

 <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

    //while loop

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your form after the php code

Answer (score 0):

You should run the PHP code before the HTML part.

Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  $delete = $_POST['select'];
  foreach ($delete as $id => $val) {
    $query="SELECT foto FROM gallery WHERE id = '$val'";
    $result1= mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      unlink($output_dir . $row[foto]); 
    }

    $query="DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id = '$val'";
    $result2= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 
  }
}
?>

<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  //while loop
</form>
```